# My elements are overlapping each other when I resize my browser

Tags: html, css

I am new in website development and needed some help with browser size. When I am on fullscreen on Safari, my code works just fine. However, when I shrink my browser's size, the elements overlap on each other.

I tried using this wrapper as it works on my previous site and it worked but it doesn't work in this site.

```
wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   width: 960px;
}
```

Below is the code for the current site I am working on.

Please ignore the comments added on it.

My Snippet:

```css
/*********** Color Palette ***********/

.dark-primary-color {
    background: #F57C00;
}
/* Darker Orange */

.default-primary-color {
    background: #FF9800;
}
/* Lighter Orange */

.light-primary-color {
    background: #FFE0B2;
}
/* Peach Orange */

.accent-color {
    background: #448AFF;
}
/* Blue */

.primary-text-color {
    color: #212121;
}
/* Black */

.secondary-text-color {
    color: #727272;
}
/* Grey */

.divider-color {
    border-color: #B6B6B6;
}
/* Light Grey */
/*********** General ***********/

#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
body {
    /* This is the CSS for body */
    
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Overflow set to hidden. Any elements outside of the window will not be shown */
    
    height: 100%;
    /* Height set to 100% means the body will extend from the top of the window to the bottom */
    
    max-height: 100%;
    /* Maximum height is limited to 100% */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in body is Montserrat */
    
    line-height: 1.5em;
    /* Line spacing is set to 1.5em */
    
    font-size: 18px;
    /* Font size set to 18px */
}
hr {
    /* This is the CSS for horizontal line */
    
    border-color: #F57C00;
    /* Color of horizontal line is dark orange */
}
h1 {
    /* This is the CSS for Header 1 */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in header 1 is Montserrat */
    
    font-size: 70px;
    /* Font size set to 70px */
    
    font-weight: 500;
    /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h2 {
    /* This is the CSS for Header 2 */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in header 2 is Montserrat */
    
    font-size: 60px;
    /* Font size set to 60px */
    
    font-weight: 500;
    /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h3 {
    /* This is the CSS for Header 3 */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in header 3 is Montserrat */
    
    font-size: 50px;
    /* Font size set to 50px */
    
    font-weight: 500;
    /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h4 {
    /* This is the CSS for Header 4 */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in header 4 is Montserrat */
    
    font-size: 40px;
    /* Font size set to 40px */
    
    font-weight: 500;
    /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
p {
    /* This is the CSS for Paragraph */
    
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Font used in paragraph is Montserrat */
    
    font-size: 18px;
    /* Font size is set to 18px */
    
    font-weight: 400;
    /* Font weight is set to 400 */
}
/*********** Header ***********/

#header {
    /* This is the CSS for header */
    
    position: absolute;
    /* Position is set to absolute */
    
    top: 0;
    /* Top is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the top of the browser */
    
    left: 0;
    /* Left is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the left of the browser */
    
    width: 100%;
    /* Width is set to 100%. The width will stretch from the browser's left to the right */
    
    height: 50px;
    /* Height is set to 50px. The height of the header is 50pixels tall */
    
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Overflow is set to hidden. Any elements outside of the header will not be shown. No scrollbar will be added */
    
    background: #F57C00;
    /* Background color is set to dark orange */
}
.headerlogo {
    /* This is the CSS for headerlogo */
    
    position: absolute;
    /* Position is set to absolute */
    
    float: left;
    /* Element will float to the left */
    
    top: 13px;
    /* Top is set to 13px. The spacing between the top of the parent and the headerlogo is 13pixels */
    
    max-height: 40px;
    /* Maximum height of headerlogo is 40px */
    
    width: auto;
    /* The width is set to auto. It will align proportionally to the height */
    
    margin-left: 70px;
    /* The spacing at the left outside of headerlogo is 70px */
    
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
    /* Font used for headerlogo is Marienda */
    
    font-size: 30px;
    /* Font size used is 30px */
    
    color: white;
    /* Color of the headerlogo is set to white */
    
    text-decoration: none;
    /* */
}
header ul {
    /* This is the CSS for header unordered list */
    
    list-style-type: none;
    /* */
    
    margin: 0;
    /* Margin is set to 0 */
    
    padding: 0;
    /* Padding is set to 0 */
    
    display: inline;
    /* */
}
header ul a {
    /* This is the CSS for header unordered a? */
    
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
header ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 0.2px;
}
header ul li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #727272;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.innertubeheader {
    margin: 15px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
/*********** Main ***********/

main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    width: 100%;
}
.innertube {
    margin: 15px;
}
.innertubeimg {
    margin: 0.1px;
    position: relative;
}
.jumbo {
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 16%;
}
.jumboh1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
}
.jumbop {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 70px;
}
p {
    color: #212121;
}
.colwrap {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.colleft {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    width: 46%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.colright {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    width: 46%;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/*********** Footer ***********/

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F57C00;
}
footer p {
    color: white;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.innertubefooter {
    margin: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
/* Right Navigation */

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    width: 00px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #444;
}
.navlogo {
    float: left;
    max-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul a {
    color: darkgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Home | Pincello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="innertubeheader">
            <a href="" class="headerlogo">Pincello</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Higeo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About Pincello</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="innertubeimg">
            <div class="jumbo">
                <h1 class="jumboh1">T E R R A ' S&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; F I N E S T</h1>
                <hr style="width:30%">
                <p class="jumbop">P H O N E S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; T A B L E T S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; L A P T O P S</p>
            </div>
            <img alt="SJ" src="012_ISC_2012_Monday_IZ3A1945.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="innertube">
            <div class="container">
                <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Who we are?</h3>
                <h3 style="text-align:center">THE MASSIVE PROJECT</h3>
                <div class="colwrap">
                    <div class="colleft">
                        <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>What is Pincello?</b>
                            <hr>
                            <br>Pincello is the leading brand of today's generation when it comes to technology.
                            <br>
                            <br>We <b>NEVER</b> felt tired being a leader.
                            <br>
                            <br>As a leader, we strongly abide to our <b>Vision and Mission</b>.
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="colright">
                        <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>Vision and Mission</b>
                            <hr>
                            <br><b>VISION:</b>
                            <br>To lead the current generation in the world of Information Technology.
                            <br>
                            <br><b>MISSION:</b>
                            <br>For the people, By the people.
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <br>
                <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Our Partner</h3>
                <h3 style="text-align:center">HIGEO</h3>
                <div class="colwrap">
                    <div class="colleft">
                        <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b>
                            <hr>
                            <br>BULLLSHIT
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="colright">
                        <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b>
                            <hr>
                            <br>BULLSHIT
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="innertubefooter">
            <p class="text-left">Copyright 2015 Pincello. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ali.cpp I updated this post so his HTML and CSS are in the same snippet, which will illustrate the problem. Concerning answering this question: Dear OP, please try yourself and _simplify_ your CSS and HTML so it's easier for us to help you. Right now you are asking us to debug an entyire page with hundreds of things, so it will be up to you to make it easy enough for us to parse and help you. You will not get a lot of help with the chunk of code you posted.

Comment: This is an enormous amount of CSS, which answerers are unlikely to want to read. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: research about @media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are after. This approach will make the `body`'s minimum width to a fixed value, so that when you re-size the window, the elements won't be overlap. You will have to scroll horizontally to see the entire page.

In case if you want to make the entire website responsive, it is better to use a framework like `bootstrap`, as you have complex positioning of elements

Change your **body** styles to this,

```
body { /* This is the CSS for body */
    position: relative;
    min-width: 900px;
    /*overflow: hidden;  Overflow set to hidden. Any elements outside of the window will not be shown */
    height: 100%; /* Height set to 100% means the body will extend from the top of the window to the bottom */
    max-height: 100%; /* Maximum height is limited to 100% */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in body is Montserrat */
    line-height: 1.5em; /* Line spacing is set to 1.5em */
    font-size: 18px; /* Font size set to 18px */
}
```

and **main** styles to this,

```
main {
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 900px;
}
```

**Below is the snippet to demonstrate the result**

```css
/*********** Color Palette ***********/

.dark-primary-color {
  background: #F57C00;
}
/* Darker Orange */

.default-primary-color {
  background: #FF9800;
}
/* Lighter Orange */

.light-primary-color {
  background: #FFE0B2;
}
/* Peach Orange */

.accent-color {
  background: #448AFF;
}
/* Blue */

.primary-text-color {
  color: #212121;
}
/* Black */

.secondary-text-color {
  color: #727272;
}
/* Grey */

.divider-color {
  border-color: #B6B6B6;
}
/* Light Grey */

/*********** General ***********/

#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
  min-width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* This is the CSS for body */
  position: relative;
  min-width: 900px;
  /*overflow: hidden;  Overflow set to hidden. Any elements outside of the window will not be shown */
  height: 100%;
  /* Height set to 100% means the body will extend from the top of the window to the bottom */
  max-height: 100%;
  /* Maximum height is limited to 100% */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in body is Montserrat */
  line-height: 1.5em;
  /* Line spacing is set to 1.5em */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Font size set to 18px */
}
hr {
  /* This is the CSS for horizontal line */
  border-color: #F57C00;
  /* Color of horizontal line is dark orange */
}
h1 {
  /* This is the CSS for Header 1 */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in header 1 is Montserrat */
  font-size: 70px;
  /* Font size set to 70px */
  font-weight: 500;
  /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h2 {
  /* This is the CSS for Header 2 */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in header 2 is Montserrat */
  font-size: 60px;
  /* Font size set to 60px */
  font-weight: 500;
  /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h3 {
  /* This is the CSS for Header 3 */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in header 3 is Montserrat */
  font-size: 50px;
  /* Font size set to 50px */
  font-weight: 500;
  /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h4 {
  /* This is the CSS for Header 4 */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in header 4 is Montserrat */
  font-size: 40px;
  /* Font size set to 40px */
  font-weight: 500;
  /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
p {
  /* This is the CSS for Paragraph */
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  /* Font used in paragraph is Montserrat */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Font size is set to 18px */
  font-weight: 400;
  /* Font weight is set to 400 */
}
/*********** Header ***********/

#header {
  /* This is the CSS for header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Position is set to absolute */
  top: 0;
  /* Top is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the top of the browser */
  left: 0;
  /* Left is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the left of the browser */
  width: 100%;
  /* Width is set to 100%. The width will stretch from the browser's left to the right */
  height: 50px;
  /* Height is set to 50px. The height of the header is 50pixels tall */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Overflow is set to hidden. Any elements outside of the header will not be shown. No scrollbar will be added */
  background: #F57C00;
  /* Background color is set to dark orange */
}
.headerlogo {
  /* This is the CSS for headerlogo */
  position: absolute;
  /* Position is set to absolute */
  float: left;
  /* Element will float to the left */
  top: 13px;
  /* Top is set to 13px. The spacing between the top of the parent and the headerlogo is 13pixels */
  max-height: 40px;
  /* Maximum height of headerlogo is 40px */
  width: auto;
  /* The width is set to auto. It will align proportionally to the height */
  margin-left: 70px;
  /* The spacing at the left outside of headerlogo is 70px */
  font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
  /* Font used for headerlogo is Marienda */
  font-size: 30px;
  /* Font size used is 30px */
  color: white;
  /* Color of the headerlogo is set to white */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* */
}
header ul {
  /* This is the CSS for header unordered list */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* */
  margin: 0;
  /* Margin is set to 0 */
  padding: 0;
  /* Padding is set to 0 */
  display: inline;
  /* */
}
header ul a {
  /* This is the CSS for header unordered a? */
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
header ul li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 0.2px;
}
header ul li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #727272;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.innertubeheader {
  margin: 15px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}
/*********** Main ***********/

main {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 900px;
}
.innertube {
  margin: 15px;
}
.innertubeimg {
  margin: 0.1px;
  position: relative;
}
.jumbo {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 16%;
}
.jumboh1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}
.jumbop {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
}
p {
  color: #212121;
}
.colwrap {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.colleft {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  width: 46%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.colright {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  width: 46%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/*********** Footer ***********/

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F57C00;
}
footer p {
  color: white;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.innertubefooter {
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
/* Right Navigation */

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 00px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #444;
}
.navlogo {
  float: left;
  max-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul a {
  color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Home | Pincello</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="innertubeheader">
      <a href="" class="headerlogo">Pincello</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Higeo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About Pincello</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="innertubeimg">
      <div class="jumbo">
        <h1 class="jumboh1">T E R R A ' S&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; F I N E S T</h1>
        <hr style="width:30%">
        <p class="jumbop">P H O N E S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; T A B L E T S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; L A P T O P S</p>
      </div>
      <img alt="SJ" src="012_ISC_2012_Monday_IZ3A1945.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="innertube">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Who we are?</h3>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">THE MASSIVE PROJECT</h3>
        <div class="colwrap">
          <div class="colleft">
            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>What is Pincello?</b>
              <hr>
              <br>Pincello is the leading brand of today's generation when it comes to technology.
              <br>
              <br>We <b>NEVER</b> felt tired being a leader.
              <br>
              <br>As a leader, we strongly abide to our <b>Vision and Mission</b>.
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="colright">
            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>Vision and Mission</b>
              <hr>
              <br><b>VISION:</b>
              <br>To lead the current generation in the world of Information Technology.
              <br>
              <br><b>MISSION:</b>
              <br>For the people, By the people.
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Our Partner</h3>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">HIGEO</h3>
        <div class="colwrap">
          <div class="colleft">
            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b>
              <hr>
              <br>BULLLSHIT
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="colright">
            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b>
              <hr>
              <br>BULLSHIT
              <br>
              <br>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    <div class="innertubefooter">
      <p class="text-left">Copyright 2015 Pincello. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but I don't think this is what anyone is after these days as the site is now unresponsive. It's a solution, though, and nice of you to go through the entirety of the code.

Comment: Yes, that is true! But as I think it is not that easy to make the above html entirely responsive under the styling he has used. In that case it will be better to use `bootstrap` or such framework. Otherwise he will have to change his styles almost entirely..But I totally agree with you.. This is bad design if you are concerned about different screen sizes! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're positioning the `.jumbo` div absolutely, which effectively takes it out of the page's flow (i.e. content will flow beneath it). Remove the `position: absolute` property, & things will no longer overlap.

**EDIT:**

Here's the block in question.

```
.jumbo {
z-index: 200;
text-align: center;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-top: 16%;
}
```

I just removed the `position: absolute` property.

```css
/*********** Color Palette ***********/
.dark-primary-color{
    background: #F57C00;
} /* Darker Orange */

.default-primary-color {
    background: #FF9800;
} /* Lighter Orange */

.light-primary-color {
    background: #FFE0B2;
} /* Peach Orange */

.accent-color {
    background: #448AFF;
} /* Blue */

.primary-text-color {
    color: #212121;
} /* Black */

.secondary-text-color {
    color: #727272;
} /* Grey */

.divider-color {
    border-color: #B6B6B6;
} /* Light Grey */



/*********** General ***********/
#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
body { /* This is the CSS for body */
    overflow: hidden; /* Overflow set to hidden. Any elements outside of the window will not be shown */
    height: 100%; /* Height set to 100% means the body will extend from the top of the window to the bottom */
    max-height: 100%; /* Maximum height is limited to 100% */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in body is Montserrat */
    line-height: 1.5em; /* Line spacing is set to 1.5em */
    font-size: 18px; /* Font size set to 18px */
}
hr { /* This is the CSS for horizontal line */
    border-color: #F57C00; /* Color of horizontal line is dark orange */
}
h1 { /* This is the CSS for Header 1 */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in header 1 is Montserrat */
    font-size: 70px; /* Font size set to 70px */
    font-weight: 500; /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h2 { /* This is the CSS for Header 2 */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in header 2 is Montserrat */
    font-size: 60px; /* Font size set to 60px */
    font-weight: 500; /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h3 { /* This is the CSS for Header 3 */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in header 3 is Montserrat */
    font-size: 50px; /* Font size set to 50px */
    font-weight: 500; /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
h4 { /* This is the CSS for Header 4 */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in header 4 is Montserrat */
    font-size: 40px; /* Font size set to 40px */
    font-weight: 500; /* Font weight is set to 500 */
}
p { /* This is the CSS for Paragraph */
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; /* Font used in paragraph is Montserrat */
    font-size: 18px; /* Font size is set to 18px */
    font-weight: 400; /* Font weight is set to 400 */
}



/*********** Header ***********/
#header { /* This is the CSS for header */
    position: absolute; /* Position is set to absolute */
    top: 0; /* Top is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the top of the browser */
    left: 0; /* Left is set to 0. There is no spacing between the header and the left of the browser */
    width: 100%; /* Width is set to 100%. The width will stretch from the browser's left to the right */
    height: 50px; /* Height is set to 50px. The height of the header is 50pixels tall */
    overflow: hidden; /* Overflow is set to hidden. Any elements outside of the header will not be shown. No scrollbar will be added */
    background: #F57C00; /* Background color is set to dark orange */
}
.headerlogo { /* This is the CSS for headerlogo */
    position: absolute; /* Position is set to absolute */
    float: left; /* Element will float to the left */ 
    top: 13px; /* Top is set to 13px. The spacing between the top of the parent and the headerlogo is 13pixels */
    max-height: 40px; /* Maximum height of headerlogo is 40px */
    width: auto; /* The width is set to auto. It will align proportionally to the height */
    margin-left: 70px; /* The spacing at the left outside of headerlogo is 70px */
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive; /* Font used for headerlogo is Marienda */
    font-size: 30px; /* Font size used is 30px */
    color: white; /* Color of the headerlogo is set to white */
    text-decoration: none; /* */
}
header ul { /* This is the CSS for header unordered list */
    list-style-type: none; /* */
    margin: 0; /* Margin is set to 0 */
    padding: 0; /* Padding is set to 0 */
    display: inline; /* */
}
header ul a { /* This is the CSS for header unordered a? */
    display: block; 
    float: right;
}
header ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px; 
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 0.2px;
}
header ul li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #727272;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.innertubeheader {
    margin: 15px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}



/*********** Main ***********/
main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    width: 100%;
}
.innertube {
    margin: 15px;
}
.innertubeimg {
    margin: 0.1px;
    position: relative;
}
.jumbo {
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 16%;
}
.jumboh1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
}
.jumbop {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 70px;
}
p {
    color: #212121;
}
.colwrap {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.colleft {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    width: 46%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.colright {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    width: 46%;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


/*********** Footer ***********/
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F57C00;
}
footer p {
    color: white;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.innertubefooter {
    margin: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
/* Right Navigation */

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    width: 00px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #444;
}
.navlogo {
    float: left;
    max-height: 40px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul a {
    color: darkgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Home | Pincello</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body id="wrapper">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="innertubeheader">
                <a href="" class="headerlogo">Pincello</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Support</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Higeo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Pincello</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Products</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div class="innertubeimg">
                <div class="jumbo">
                    <h1 class="jumboh1">T E R R A ' S&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; F I N E S T</h1>
                    <hr style="width:30%">
                    <p class="jumbop">P H O N E S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; T A B L E T S &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; L A P T O P S</p>
                </div>
                <img alt="SJ" src="012_ISC_2012_Monday_IZ3A1945.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="innertube">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Who we are?</h3>
                    <h3 style="text-align:center">THE MASSIVE PROJECT</h3>
                    <div class="colwrap">
                        <div class="colleft">
                            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>What is Pincello?</b><hr><br>Pincello is the leading brand of today's generation when it comes to technology.<br><br>We <b>NEVER</b> felt tired being a leader.<br><br>As a leader, we strongly abide to our <b>Vision and Mission</b>.<br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="colright">
                            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>Vision and Mission</b><hr><br><b>VISION:</b><br>To lead the current generation in the world of Information Technology.<br><br><b>MISSION:</b><br>For the people, By the people.<br><br><br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:18px; color:#F57C00">Our Partner</h3>
                    <h3 style="text-align:center">HIGEO</h3>
                    <div class="colwrap">
                        <div class="colleft">
                            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b><hr><br>BULLLSHIT<br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="colright">
                            <p align="justify" style="font-size:30px"><b>TITLE</b><hr><br>BULLSHIT<br><br>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="innertubefooter">
                <p class="text-left">Copyright 2015 Pincello. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Happy you took on this challenge. Could you copy over the provided snippet to your answer and edit it appropriatly? If it works, I'll +1 you.

Comment: @somethinghere done.

Comment: I just tested it by clicking 'copy snippet to answer' and replaced the `.jumbo` class with your code but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Sorry to trouble you but could you just use the copy snippet to answer and amend it there? Then I can run it and verify...

Comment: @somethinghere it's hard to see in the preview here. I copied all this code & fixed it in my editor, then tested the page in Chrome.

Comment: @somethinghere Thanks. I updated my answer with the full fixed code. ;)